# Delete a direct message without admin presence

Tags: python, slack-api

My question is simply: Which is the correct api (and way) to delete a direct message in slack, using the slack client for python?

The situation is that:

- User x sends a direct message to the chatbot.
- The bot for security needs to delete the received message.
- The api tested for that is [`chat.delete`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete) with the bot using an
  oauth token of an admin account.
- `chat.delete` receives as arguments the channel id, the timestamp of
  the message, and as_user in true.

The problem is, that the slack documentation says that for delete a message, the admin (owner of the token that the bot is using) needs had been joined to the channel where the target messages lives. But of course, the admin isn't on the private message between the user and the bot.

Because that the api returns an error and says *Channel not found*.

If the admin test the command with the bot, the bot can delete the message, but this is because the admin is on the private conversation.

And, if instead of admin oauth token, you use the bot token to request to the `chat.delete` api, the throwed error is *can't delete the message*. I suppose that is because for delete, you need admin token and not bot token.
But well, what is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Only admins can delete messages from others user. But I believe if you install your app by an admin, the user token of the app (called access token) will inherit that right from the admin. If you then use the app's access token it should work to delete the message with `chat.delete`.

Comment: @Erik Kalkoken thanks for your suggestion.
I think that idea before, but the problem of that, if you use the admin Access token to perform the bot tasks, the users of the chat see the account owner of the  token (the admin) instead of see the bot chatting with the users.

Comment: you are correct, but that was not what I was suggesting. install the app with an admin, continue to use the bot token for all communication (so it visibly comes from the bot) and use the user token of the app (which then has the admin rights) only for deleting the messages.

Comment: @Erik Kalkoken thanks eric for your aclaration;
That aproach that you said, is how we was trying to use the bot; but the problem is, when the user that is talking with the commander user (the dude that is interacting with the bot) is the bot, and not the admin, when the admin try to delete the message, he can't because the admin isn't pressent on the conversation. The answer of the api is
Channel not found 
Consider that the conversation between the user and the bot, must be through only direct message, and no a public  / group channel :P 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of research, the result is sadli.

Directly with the slack mechanism of the api, only the owner of a direct message can delete it, but an admin can't read, modify or delete any direct message of other person.

A slack owner can review and view qthect messages of other users, only if have the business subscription, and using some tools than let download these pms, but not modify, or delete it.

Thanks for all guys!